# How can I view HTTP only cookies in OSX?

Tags: web-browsing, cookies

I have a website I'm investigating and want to view HTTP-only cookies in Firefox, Safari, or Chrome.

How can I view these special cookies in OSX?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome choose View->Developer->Developer tools (or key alt-cmd-I) and the choose the resources tab.

In Safari Develop->Show Page Resources (key alt-cmd-A) choose the storage view. To turn the developer tools on go to Preferences->Advanced and tick the bottom box "Show Develop menu in Menu bar" For more info see the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web_Developer_Extension_%28external%29) plugin for Firefox has a "Cookies -> View Cookie Information" menu choice that displays cookies for a given URL. It differentiates cookies based on http / https for each domain.